# What are the odds against four people independently getting a date wrong by the same margin?

Tags: probability

a friend recently asked me a question and I’m not a mathematician so can anyone help me? What are the chances against four people incorrectly and independently remembering the same date of an event 38 years ago and by the same margin of two years? Also, what are the chances of collusion to arrive at the same date? I would greatly appreciate it if you answered in plain English rather than Maths stating the progressive chances of 2,3, or 4 all getting it wrong at the same time. Many thanks in advance

Comment: Could you explain what exactly you mean?  Do you mean the event surely took place 38 years ago but 2 people specifically place it at 40 years and 2 people specifically place it at 36? Or do they remember it at various times within two years.  "what are the chances of collusion to arrive at the same date?"  What does "chances of collusion" mean?  I have no idea what that means.

Comment: Hi fleablood, as I understand it, four people claim an event happened in 1978 when it could only factually have happened in 1980.

Comment: This is an actual occurrence?  We have to make some assumptions about in general how general the spread is.  This seems unlikely but we must assume 38 years ago these people were teenagers or likely younger?  There may be a defining event as a cut off upper date.  For example the know it had to have happen early in high school but definately not after graduation so the think it was the freshman year but it was their junior year.  Or they could be mistaking it with a similar event. "Oh wait; I keep think I did that when I was dating Cindy cause its so like her but if it was Wendy, well..."

Comment: Fleablood, yes it was an actual event. One parent and three siblings claim a specific year two years before it actually happened. The three siblings claim it coincided incorrectly with concurrent events in their life in 1978 which was impossible!

Comment: I would say there were circumstances that made them misassociate with other events and that caused the dates to be off and it is not random but that there are reasons for it.

Comment: You are correct fleablood, there are other factors accounting for their misassociation, which are commonly known as lying. I'm simply seeking a statistical assessment of the odds against four people randomly arriving at the same incorrect date independently. It would appear that may not be possible but thanks for your interest

Comment: It *is* possible but it would required more information than we have.

Comment: Perhaps I haven't made the question as clear as I should have. The odds I am seeking are not in relation to the four persons I mention but rather to four imaginary random persons arriving at the same incorrect date by chance therefore allowing me to make a statistical comparison to reality.

Comment: Not enough information.

Answer (score 1):

In plain English, your question does not have a mathematical answer unless you make several assumptions.

Here is one possible way to start. Assume all you're interested in is getting the year right (not the day of the year). Assume that each of the five guesses $36, 37, 38, 39, 40$ years ago is equally likely, and that no other guesses are allowed. Assume that each guesser guesses one of those years at random. Then the chance that all four  guess $36$ is one in $625$ and that they all guess $40$ is the same, so the chance that they agree on a date off by two years is about $2$ in $625$, or $1$ in $300$.

But these assumptions are probably unrealistic. They might have an even wider margin of possible guesses. They might have some information that makes those guesses not equally likely. There might be reasons that say their choices aren't really independent (since they are thinking about the same history).

So in the end this is not really a mathematical question.

Comment: Ethan, thank you for your answer. Not being a mathematician perhaps my expectations are a little too high. At least you have given some odds regardless of the assupmtions. Thanks again.

Comment: @RobRoy Not "regardless of the assumptions". You mean "depending on the assumptions".

Comment: My apologies. My grammar is about as accurate as my maths!

Comment: Hmmm... Each date equally likely is an assumption.  I think it be more likely that it'd be bell curved shape.  But with what deviation.  Your are right though.  We can not answer this without assumptions.  And I would suggest that other memory associations are causing the faulty memories

Comment: @fleablood Yes, I think a bell shape is more likely. But I didn't want to try to guess at a standard deviation and then do the extra work. It iis really a question about psychology more than mathematics.